# Typing caret in CLion irrespective of keymaps doesnt work

Tags: clion

I cannot type caret in my IDE ( CLion ) . Everywhere else for example here ( ^ ) , its not a problem. But just not in the IDE. Changing keymap from Eclipse to Netbeans or anything else doesnt help.

Since, there is a clion tag in this site, I hope, I can await answers here.
Any idea where I should start looking?

Comment: *"I can type caret in my IDE"*: so can you? Or not?

Comment: edited. sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have "Shift+6" accelerator.
Please, check in `File|SEttings...` dialog
[image]